# How to make a gRPC firestore listen request in Rust?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rust, grpc

Using gRPC bindings from https://github.com/gkkachi/firestore-grpc I was able to puzzle together something that is seemingly working but does not receive any content:

Creating the request:

```rust
    let req = ListenRequest {
        database: format!("projects/{}/databases/(default)", project_id),
        labels: HashMap::new(),
        target_change: Some(TargetChange::AddTarget(Target {
            // "Rust" in hex: https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/51
            target_id: 0x52757374,
            once: false,
            target_type: Some(TargetType::Documents(DocumentsTarget {
                documents: vec![users_collection],
            })),
            resume_type: None,
        })),
    };
```

Sending it:

```rust
    let mut req = Request::new(stream::iter(vec![req]));
    let metadata = req.metadata_mut();
    metadata.insert(
        "google-cloud-resource-prefix",
        MetadataValue::from_str(&db).unwrap(),
    );

    println!("sending request");
    let res = get_client(&token).await?.listen(req).await?;
    let mut res = res.into_inner();
    while let Some(msg) = res.next().await {
        println!("getting response");
        dbg!(msg);
    }
```

(full code [in this repo](https://github.com/rksm/firestore-streaming-test-rs/blob/master/src/main.rs)).

The request can be made but the stream does not contain any actual content. The only hint I get from the debug logs is

```
[2021-10-27T14:54:39Z DEBUG h2::codec::framed_write] send frame=GoAway { error_code: NO_ERROR, last_stream_id: StreamId(0) } 
[2021-10-27T14:54:39Z DEBUG h2::proto::connection] Connection::poll; connection error error=GoAway(b"", NO_ERROR, Library)
```

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: I am going to try to repro. Have you tried using another gRPC client e.g. [`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to test your configuration?

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. The gist I provided will require some additional things to reproduce. To make it easier I created https://github.com/rksm/firestore-streaming-test-rs. It should only need a service account credentials and then should be able to run as is.

Comment: It's a black box, isn't it? My Rust foo is weak but I'm familiar with Google's libraries. I've not actually used a Firestore listener from e.g. Go so this is new territory for me. It would be good to know whether anyone has ever gotten this to work. In the Gist, did you have problems using a `collection_id` of e.g. `"users".into()`? You're providing the fully-qualified path

Comment: The `select: None` and `r@where: None` also suggest not query anything which is what we observe. No results.

Comment: I added a `Projection` and now I'm `getting response`'s, just `Unknown` (gprc-status header missing, mapped from HTTP status code 200` (200 can't be bad) but, I don't understand why :-)

Comment: Hmm yeah so the target can also be a [DocumentsTarget](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#target) in which case the request looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/rksm/61841fed1deff838890422ad82878197), which I think is correct (playing with the parameters doesn't make a difference). But the `send frame=GoAway` hints towards not correctly using the client. That piece is send from it and I'll probably need to keep the connection open to allow receiving responses...

Comment: And for the `StructuredQuery`: not having a `select` or `where` seems to be OK. If you want to stream an entire collection as is such as `projects/{projectid}/databases/{dbname}/documents/users` then parent should be `projects/{projectid}/databases/{dbname}/documents` and the `from` field can be a `CollectionSelector` with `collection_id` `"users"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial thing I was missing as pointed out in the [rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/streaming-from-google-firestore-with-grpc/66497/2) was that the request stream was immediately ending which caused the connection to close. The `send frame=GoAway` was actually send by the client (facepalm).

To keep the connection open and receive responses we can keep the input stream pending: `Request::new(stream::iter(vec![req]).chain(stream::pending()))`. There will be a better way to set things up and keep control over subsequent input requests but this is enough to fix the example.